# octahedral interstitial sites located entirely within a full hexagonal HCP unit cell at a height of $c/4$ up from the bottom of the unit cell

Tags: crystal-structure, crystallography

I have been trying to visualize and find the number of them for a while, through the image attached. [image]

I can't tell whether the c/4 part includes the octahedral site or not...how should I go about approaching this problem?

Comment: Those white dots are the octahedral/tetrahedral sites (respectively). Those white dots on the left are at c/4 and 3c/4...

Comment: so would you say there are 3 full sites in the c/4 region or 0?